# How do I restart Raspberry Pi from a remote system?

Tags: raspbmc

I have mounted my Raspberry Pi videos folder into my Ubuntu 10.04 system. I can paste different videos to mounted directory along with videos folder in Raspberry Pi whenever I require.

The problem is I want to restart the Raspberry Pi every time manually to play newly pasted content in the videos folder. So, I decided that I want to reboot the Raspberry Pi by writing the script and run it on my local system.

Is there a command available to restart the Raspberry Pi through my local system?

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just restart your video player, instead of rebooting the whole Pi?

Comment: I need to restart two raspberry pi from my ubuntu system(via shell script).@Arne

Answer (score 19):

something like this might help:

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.1.XXX 'echo raspberry | sudo shutdown -r now'
```

this command connects to your raspberry using SSH and issues the reboot command, make sure you replace 192.168.1.XXX with the real address and pi/raspberry with your real login/password.

Comment: dude,i run this command in my terminal "ssh root@192.168.1.106 'echo openelec | shutdown -r now'" then it prompts password, i was typed and it throws "sh:shutdown:command not found"

Comment: try to specify the full path to the `shutdown` command, you may find if using `which shutdown` while logged to your pi.

Comment: ssh root@192.168.1.106 reboot this command is working, if i suppose to reboot two raspberry pi at a time means  how to do

Comment: ssh root@192.168.1.106 reboot; ssh root@192.168.1.107 reboot ? put several commands in line, separate with ";" and specify correct IP addresses.

Comment: Does "sudo shutdown" and "Sudo halt" do the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Also note that user name prefixed by @ can vary from vendor of your OS, for example
Arch Linux : root (and you do not need sudo)
Debian : pi (you need sudo)
Pidora : any name you chosen at setup (and you need sudo plus password)

I setup   a user in Pidora with same name as I use at Ubuntu, so I do not need to specify any @ prefix.

Comment: Through this command "ssh root@192.168.1.106 reboot" i can reboot my raspberry, but i need to reboot morethan one raspberry pi at time. How to do

Comment: Run the command twice ? Or write a script to run it for both IP addresses